# Sybase/Sap sql: converting from cp1251 to utf8

Tags: sql, windows, character-encoding, sybase, asa

Default charset in base is Windows1251, but when I use "for json" statement, result presents in "utf8"

Is it possible convert some column to ut8, using sql?

I try this code

```
select 
  1 as "tag",
  null as "parent",
  "period" as "!1!period",
  "nazva" as "!1!nazva",
  "DogovorNumber" as "!1!DogovorNumber"
  from "dba"."Myk_Orgs_for_1C"(@cmonth = 3,@cyear = 2022)
  order by 3 asc for json explicit
```

But my columns values shown like this
"nazva":"Р“РћР РћРЇРќ РќРђIР Рђ"

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Р“РћР\xa0РћРЇРќ РќРђIР\xa0Рђ'.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')` returns `ГОРОЯН НАIРА`. Here `\xa0` is ` ` (U+00A0,  *No-Break Space*)…

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround the encoding issue with **output** statement:

```
select 
  1 as "tag",
  null as "parent",
  "period" as "!1!period",
  "nazva" as "!1!nazva",
  "DogovorNumber" as "!1!DogovorNumber"
  from "dba"."Myk_Orgs_for_1C"(@cmonth = 3,@cyear = 2022)
  order by 3 asc for json explicit
;
output to 'C:\\out.json' format text escapes on escape character '\' delimited by '' encoding 'CP-1251'
```